# How to remove duplicate values from a query

Tags: postgresql, duplicates

I have the following issue, I need to remove duplicate values from a specific column I query. No deleting!(ClassID)

| SchoolNo | Schoolyear | Schoolgrade | Classname | ClassId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 65432 | 2001 | 5 | ab | 441 |
| 65432 | 2001 | 5 | cd | 442 |
| 65432 | 2001 | 6 | a | 443 |
| 65432 | 2001 | 6 | b | 444 |
| 56838 | 2001 | 5 | ab | 445 |
| 56838 | 2001 | 5 | cd | 446 |
| 56838 | 2001 | 6 | ab | 445 |
| 56838 | 2001 | 6 | ef | 447 |
| 12726 | 2001 | 5 | ms | 448 |
| 12726 | 2001 | 6 | ms | 448 |

If you look at the values of classId I have repeated class numbers because some special schools sometimes put 2 classes together for both grades. The problem is my query needs to show only 1 classid value. No repeats. Therefore we can remove any extra class that is repeated in value and only show for grade 5.

In other words my table should at end up looking like this.

| SchoolNo | Schoolyear | Schoolgrade | Classname | ClassId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 65432 | 2001 | 5 | ab | 441 |
| 65432 | 2001 | 5 | cd | 442 |
| 65432 | 2001 | 6 | a | 443 |
| 65432 | 2001 | 6 | b | 444 |
| 56838 | 2001 | 5 | ab | 445 |
| 56838 | 2001 | 5 | cd | 446 |
| 56838 | 2001 | 6 | ef | 447 |
| 12726 | 2001 | 5 | ms | 448 |

The code generally looks like this.

```
select schoolno,schoolyear,schoolgrade,classname,classId
from classgroup cg
```

How should I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select cg1.* from classgroup cg1
left join classgroup cg2 on (cg1."ClassId"=cg2."ClassId" and cg1."Schoolgrade"<cg2."Schoolgrade")
where cg2."Schoolgrade" is null
```

The output:
[image]

Comment: Hey so your query worked in the case that repeated classid's dont repeat themselves. However I am getting instead of a 5 a 6 even through the logic sounds fine. is there a way to apply a case statement to force it?

Comment: your method was perfect. Quick question what is the "" for? is there a difference between cg2.schoolgrade and scg."schoolgrade"?

Comment: Use "" when column names contain capital letters.

Answer (score 2):

maybe you can do it like this:

```sql
select
  first_value(schoolno) over w,
  first_value(schoolyear) over w,
  first_value(schoolgrade) over w,
  first_value(classname) over w,
  first_value(classId) over w
FROM
  classgroup
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY schoolno, schoolyear, classId ORDER BY schoolgrade);
```

You partition the data by `schoolno`, `schoolyear` and `classId` and order by `schoolgrade` then take only the first row of each partition.

Note: the syntax may be a bit off since I couldn't test it

Comment: I did a test on your query and it is OK. Nice approach.

Comment: I have given it a try but i got the same result... it is not removing the 2nd row of similar classID the repeated classid is showing twice.